# set value of textarea using radio button jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the value of a textarea using jQuery.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $('#bericht').val('foobar'); 
    $('input[name=taal]:radio').click(function () {
        alert('click');
        $('#bericht').val('foobar');
    });
});
```

When uncommenting the 2nd line it works fine. Also the alert works when clicking. However the value is never set when clicking the radio button... How could that be?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle showing replicating this problem?

Comment: Nope cant :( replicated the exact thing, and there it does work... Nice website btw, never used it before. http://jsfiddle.net/JE3aQ/

Comment: Did you forget to include jquery? If not, does any errors come out in the console?

Comment: I found the problem, the textarea had tinymce set on it, when removed it did work. Now lets see how to get them both to work.... :-p

Comment: Final working code =  http://jsfiddle.net/JE3aQ/1/ thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/evqdW/)

```
$('input[name="taal"]').click(function () {
    alert('click');
    $('#bericht').val('foobar');
});
```

**or**

```
$('input:radio[name="taal"]').click(function () {
    alert('click');
    $('#bericht').val('foobar');
});
```

Comment: Just FYI - you don't need attribute selector to be enclosed in quotes.  OP's JS code works.

Comment: Yes, it will work for this also: `$('input[name=taal]').click(function () {
    alert('click');
    $('#bericht').val('foobar');
});`

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with your HTML. Please ensure the attribute id="bericht" is set on the `<textarea>` tag.

Here is the sample - that works with your javascript code - http://jsfiddle.net/mt4hM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have another plugin set on the textarea, that overrules it?

If so, you might need to enter through the plugins api.

I had a similar issue with TinyMCE.

Comment: This was the case, thank you! How did you solve it to be able to use both this and TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

try set some class to radio, and use it on jquery code. like this:

```
$('.myRadio').click(function () {
    $('#bericht').val('foobar');
});
```